# How do I stop IntelliJ generating .js files for my .ts source

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

I have a mixed Java/Typescript project which uses Maven as a build tool together with the [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) and I can build my project as expected from the command line.  I have an issue however with IntelliJ  2018.2 in that it keeps transpiling `.js` files for my `.ts` source code.  The `.js` files are picked up by the Jest test runner so test are run twice and cause the Maven build to fail as they do not pass linting.

I have the TypeScript Language Service enabled as if that is disabled IntelliJ shows me errors throughout my TypeScript code.  If I un-tick "Recompile on changes" then every .ts file shows a prompt at the top asking if I want to "Compile TypeScript to JavaScript? Yes/No/Configure".

Is it possible to configure IntelliJ so it writes `.js` files into a separate build directory (which is excluded) in the same way create-react-app works?

Comment: Make sure that 'Enable TypeScript compiler' is disabled in Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript, and that you don't have TypeScript file watcher set up in Preferences | Tools | File Watchers

Comment: @JoeYdoanRauzes I'm not sure what version of IntelliJ you are using - there is no "Enable TypeScript compiler" option in 2018.2, just "TypeScript Language Service" and I have no File Watchers menu under Tools

Comment: oh i have done that long ago.. but now when i look again its actually you can uncheck Recompile on changes, yes right no more File Watchers menu, i have IntelliJ Idea ultimate 2018.1

Comment: I assume you then see the prompt "Compile TypeScript to JavaScript? Yes/No/Configure" at the top of every .ts file?

Comment: actually it doesnt show in my intelliJ. or mine is really not good

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure to disable **Recompile on changes** in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript**.
To write `.js` files to the separate folder, set the `"outDir"` in your `tsconfig.json` to the desired path. If you aren't using `tsconfig.json`, you can specify `--outDir <DIRECTORY>` in **Options:** field. But I'd strongly recommend setting up `tsconfig.json` instead of passing cmd options to compiler - using tsconfig.json is an industry standard for working with TypeScript applications

Comment: My `tsconfig.json` contains `"outDir": "build/dist"` but IntelliJ does not respect that, I'll turn off **Recompile on changes** and see if that has any negative effects

Comment: the built-in compiler does normally respect `"outDir"`; it must be a problem with your configuration

Comment: The same is happening for me.  I still see .js and .js.map files for every ts file.  I have an outdir configured.

Comment: Yes!! This is extremely annoying and it occurs randomly and nobody is fixing it.

Comment: The additional issue is that once it has generated them, it does no cleanup when you turn off Recompile on changes.